# Calling @cacheEvict and @Cacheable together Spring

Tags: caching, ehcache, spring-annotations, spring-cache

It may be very simple but I would like to know if I can call @Cacheable and @CacheEvict together on one method as below:

```
@Cacheable(value = "empListCache")
@CacheEvict(value = "empListCache", allEntries = true)
public List<Emply> findAllEmplys() throws SomeException
```

Is the above code evict the empListCache each time the method is called or will be only evicted when the cache is full?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do exactly? Yes, you can do that but that basically completely defeats the purpose of caching.

`@CacheEvict` runs by default **after** the method invocation. So the declaration above would have the purpose of caching the list with an identical key (as your method has no argument) and then clear completely the cache.

Long story short: if you remove the two annotations, you get the exact same result (except the cache "emptyListCache" is not cleared).